# I have the required fields for user login how to bypass the nextauth login page and perform the authorize method

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I create a custom user registration because nextauth does not support registration. Everything works correctly but I do not know how after a successful registration of the user immediately log him in the credentials that he gave during registration.

As far as I can see, the `signIn` method from nextauth does not allow any credentials to be passed on to it. Redirects only to the login subpage.

I also did not find any endpoint that provides nextauth to which I can pass parameters so as to log in the user.

In fact, it is enough to call the `authorize` method that is in nextauth, unfortunately, there is no possibility to export it or there is no way to call it from the call to api level and it is a pity because with it I could log in the user.

**User flow**  
User registers if the registration is successful, he is immediately logged in credentials that he provided during registration

**My registration**

```
async function handleRegister(
    username: string,
    email: string,
    password: string
  ) {
    const registerUser = await fetch(
      `${process.env.API_URL}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username,
          email,
          password,
        }),
      }
    );

    const registerResponse = await registerUser.json();

    if (registerResponse.user) {
     // TODO: Login with NextAuth
    }
  }
```

`[...nextauth].ts`

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        identifier: {
          label: "Email or Username",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "jsmith",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/local`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        );
        const user = await res.json();
        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60,
    encode: async ({ secret, token }) => {
      const encodedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign(token!, secret, {
        algorithm: "HS256",
      });

      return encodedToken;
    },
    decode: async ({ secret, token }) => {
      const decodedToken = jsonwebtoken.verify(token!, secret, {
        algorithms: ["HS256"],
      });

      return decodedToken as JWT;
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async (token, user, account) => {
      const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
      if (isSignIn) {
        token.jwt = user.jwt;
        token.id = user.user.id;
        token.name = user.user.username;
        token.role = user.user.user_role;
        token.email = user.user.email;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub!;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});
```

Comment: Hi, Were you able to find the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to login with credentials e.g

```
const response: SignInResponse | undefined = await signIn(
  "credentials",
    {
      redirect: false,
      email: "example@user.com",
      password: "12345678",
    }
);
```